# What is the benefit of using Entity types over Entity bundles from a usability perspective

Tags: views, panels, flags, entities

I have installed ECK and created different entity types for a project management website. For example Project, Group, Task, Report.

Each entity type requires at least one bundle, so I named the bundle the same as the name of the Entity type (which ECK does by default).
I did not add custom Entity properties to any type. This is mainly because there are many modules that don't support Entity properties (yet).

I also added an extra bundle 'Issues' to the entity type Task.

The problem that I now face, is that a lot of modules have limitions in the way they use and display data, in that it must be configured for one specific entity type. For example, each view, each flag and each panel must be based on one entity type. Any module that deals with entity fields must create multiple instances for each entity type.

This requires me now to create a lot of views and flags for all entity types that I created. Not a really efficient or usable situation.

So after all this, I must conclude that I would better have created only one ECK entity type called 'Entity' or 'Project element' and add the Project, Group, Task and Report as bundles.  They only share some basic system/ECK fields anyway like title author date created etc.

Am I right, that using multiple Entity types is actually not necessary and even not recommended, unless there are many bundles that could share a lot of entity properties?